# Relating integrals to a square

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration

The following problem is a problem in my linear algebra book.

(a) Compute the following integrals (you can use a calculator) and state the relationship between them.

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x^2\mathop{dx} \hspace{1em} \int_{-1}^{1} (x^2 - 1/3)^2 \mathop{dx} \hspace{1em} \int_{-1}^{1} (x^2 + x - 1/3)^2 \mathop{dx} $$

I evaluated the integrals and got $2/3, 8/45$, and $38/45$ respectively. The relationship is that the sum of the first two integrals equals the second.

(b) Evaluate the integral

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x(x^2 - 1/3) \mathop{dx} $$

I evaluated the integral to be $0$.

(c) Explain how these results relate to the fact that the diagonal of a unit square is equal to $\sqrt{2}$ units.

I'm not sure how to do (c) at all. I tried graphing the functions etc, but I can't find any relationship between these integrals and a square. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 2):

$$[x+(x^2-\frac13)]^2=x^2+(x^2+\frac13)^2 +2x(x^2-\frac 13)$$

Integrating both sides gives what you found:

$\frac {38}{45}=\frac 23+\frac 8{45}$

And:

$\int^1_{-1}x(x^2-\frac 13)=0$

Let x=a and $(x^2-\frac13)=b$, so we have:

$ a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2 $

This is possible only if a=b=1 which gives:

$c^2=a^2+b^2=2\rightarrow c=\sqrt2 $

where c is diagonal of unit square.

Comment: How did you get $a^2 + b^2 = a + b$?

Comment: I'm a little bit lost by how you introduced the unit square.

Comment: Even after your edit, I'm a little bit lost. Could you please explain how $a, b$ were introduced, and how the square came up?

Comment: @jaja624, that was a typo, I corrected it. we can always consider  a and b in relation $a^2+b^2=c^2$ as sides of a square, if a=b=1 then it is a unit square.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about how we got $a^2 + b^2 = (a + b)^2$ in the first place. Could you please clarify? I'm not sure how we went from the integrals to that equation